# Java, ASM: How to Get Opcode Name and TagValue from ASM InsnNode?

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I am working on some class file analysis and I am working on using ASM to read classes.  In Javap the opcode and the tagName and tagValue are printed inline, but in each AbstractInsnNode, I see only fields for the int (and not the tagValue)

```
for(AbstractInsnNode abstractInsnNode : instructionList)
{
   System.out.println("\tOpcode: " + + abstractInsnNode.getOpcode()  +
        " type: " + abstractInsnNode.getType());
}
```

How do I get the of the instruction with ASM, such as:

```
5: invokeinterface #6,  2 // InterfaceMethod java/util/Set.add:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
```

And in the case of loading strings and constants etc, I need access to those values as well.  This usually come from the `tagValue` of javap.  I don't just need to print these, I also need programatic access to the values.

I need access to the basic operation information, eg these fields:

```
 jvmOperations": [{
        "byteOffset": 0,
        "constantPoolIndex": null,
        "opCode": 42,
        "opCodeName": "aload_0",
        "type": null,
        "tagName": null,
        "tagValue": null
    }, {
        "byteOffset": 1,
        "constantPoolIndex": null,
        "opCode": 180,
        "opCodeName": "getfield",
        "type": null,
        "tagName": "Field",
        "tagValue": "val$foo:Lcom/example/graph/demo/Foo;"
    }, {
        "byteOffset": 4,
        "constantPoolIndex": null,
        "opCode": 182,
        "opCodeName": "invokevirtual",
        "type": null,
        "tagName": "Method",
        "tagValue": "com/example/graph/demo/Foo.doSomething:()Ljava/lang/Integer;"
    }, {
        "byteOffset": 7,
        "constantPoolIndex": null,
        "opCode": 176,
        "opCodeName": "areturn",
        "type": null,
        "tagName": null,
        "tagValue": null
    }]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check the source of the [ASMifier](http://websvn.ow2.org/filedetails.php?repname=asm&path=%2Ftags%2FASM_5_0_4%2Fsrc%2Forg%2Fobjectweb%2Fasm%2Futil%2FASMifier.java) and [Textifier](http://websvn.ow2.org/filedetails.php?repname=asm&path=%2Ftags%2FASM_5_0_4%2Fsrc%2Forg%2Fobjectweb%2Fasm%2Futil%2FTextifier.java) classes how they print stuff out..